# Finding elements with PowerShell and Selenium 4

Tags: powershell, selenium, powershell-5.1, selenium4

I am working on updating some PowerShell code that previously worked with Selenium 3.141. I have the following code snippet:

```
$url = "https://<webpage.com>"
$options = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu")
$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($options)
$driver.Navigate().GoToURL($url)
$driver.FindElementById("username")
```

With Selenium 4.0, FindElementById no longer works:

> Method invocation failed because [OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver]
> does not contain a method named 'FindElementById'

Looking at https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/what-is-deprecated-in-selenium4/, I see that this ought to work (in Java):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username"))
```

But I do not know how to translate that to PowerShell ($driver.FindElement(By.id("username")) does not work).

Any idea how I can find an element by ID (or class, xpath, etc.) with PowerShell and Selenium 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the fully qualified class name of [`By`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html):

```
$driver.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::Id("username"))
```

The `::` accessor is used because the [`Id()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id(java.lang.String)) method is a static member of the `By` class.